# IntelliJ IDEA Grails 3.0 Error

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a new Grails project with IntelliJ IDEA using the new grails-3.0 M1 SDK but when running create-app I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
```

With previous grail versions works fine (I got the environment variables configured correctly)

Any workarounds about it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use the grails integration in idea? Grails 3 is so different, I doubt that will work. Just create-app from the command line, and import the project into idea from the build.gradle file that creates

Comment: I've tried that and ye, I can import the structure into IDEA but I still can't use grail commands (to create controllers etc.) so it's not of much use

Comment: No, until it's updated to work with grails 3, you'll need to use the command line or the grails shell to issue commands

Comment: Don't forget, you're trying a milestone release (not even a beta, or release candidate), so you're living on the cutting edge, and tooling might take a bit to catch up with you ;-)

Comment: Posted as an answer ;-)  good luck! Grails 3 looks brilliant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you trying to use the grails integration in idea? Grails 3 is so different, I doubt that will work. Just create-app from the command line, and import the project into idea from the build.gradle file that creates.

Until it's updated to work with grails 3, you'll need to use the command line or the grails shell to issue commands

Don't forget, you're trying a milestone release (not even a beta, or release candidate), so you're living on the cutting edge, and tooling might take a bit to catch up with you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Grails 3 uses gradle.
So create your app with grails create-app, and you can open the project as a gradle one.
You loose the grails view, but it works.

Comment: this can go as a comment

Comment: You don't lose the grails view. You will just not be able to execute it using the Run and Debug buttons.

Comment: @biniam_Ethiopia so how to activate grails view in that case? There is no grails in "add framework support"

Comment: @Normal The grails view is available when you run create-app. But, you cannot execute the application using IntelliJ but you can do that from the command line. This is because IntelliJ still has no support for Grails 3 (may be in upcoming versions ...)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no other java paths on your system, sometimes it may happen in windows that before your actual path you have something like "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in your system path. if you have this just delete it and run a new cmd and test again.