# cannot initialize Grails 3.0.1 app in IntelliJ 14.1

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-3.0

I am trying to initialize a Grails 3.0.1 application in IntelliJ 14.1, but `run-app` fails.

I get the following error:

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter"
```

output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\ops\grails-3.0.1 -Dbase.dir=C:\Users\shay "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\ops\grails-3.0.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\ops\grails-3.0.1\dist\grails-bootstrap-3.0.1.jar org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\ops\grails-3.0.1/conf/groovy-starter.conf "create-app grails3.1 -plain-output"Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter
        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: there are already lots of Q/As about it e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261484/intellij-idea-grails-3-0-error. in general it is not yet supported.  try to run it as gradle project. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136970

Comment: I regularly run Grails 3.0.1 apps in IntelliJ 14.1.  I open the `Application.groovy` class and run it as I would run any class with a `main` method in IntelliJ.  I don't use any of their Grails tooling offered by IntelliJ and I don't invoke a Gradle build.  It all just works for me in the Community Edition.

Comment: I'm switching to Grails 2.x.x in order to use it with iIntelliJ 14 for now.